# Use AlamofireObjectMapper to create func return an object

Tags: swift, alamofire, func, objectmapper

I am about to use AlamofireObjectMapper extension to map JSON response from a server and create a func to return the object

I have wrote these code of `func`

```
   func downloadPokemonDetails1(completed: DownloadComplete)-> (Pokemon?) {
        let url = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject { (response: Response<Pokemon, NSError>) in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                print(response.result.error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            let pokemon1 = response.result.value
            return pokemon1
        }
    }
```

Herer is my Constanst.swift (contain `DownloadComplete` closure)

```
import Foundation

let URL_BASE = "http://pokeapi.co"
let URL_POKEMON = "/api/v1/pokemon/"

typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

I don't know why the func `downloadPokemonDetails1` giving the error `un-expected Non-void return value in void function`

My `Pokemon` Class

```
lass Pokemon: Mappable {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        id <- map["id"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your Pokemon class?

Comment: Hi I have edit the question include the Pokemon class. func downloadPokemonDetails1 is included in Pokemon class also.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should go like this :

```
func downloadPokemonDetails1(completed: (Pokemon?) -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject { (response: Response<Pokemon, NSError>) in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
            print(response.result.error.debugDescription)
            return
        }
        let pokemon1 = response.result.value
        completed(pokemon1)
    }
}


self.downloadPokemonDetails1({
        [weak weakSelf = self]
        pokemon in
        if let unwrappedPokemon = pokemon {
            weakSelf.label.text = unwrappedPokemon.name
        } else {
            //show some error
        }
})
```

In your code, you try to return value from block, not from your function. I think the better way is to return pokemon object using block.

Hope it help you

Comment: Hi thanks alot for yrs suggest. Anyway why do we need 2 func to get the object from URL? how do we update UI only after already get the object?

Comment: Of course, you don't need to have 2 func to get an object from URL. You can update your UI from alamofire response block

Comment: So is this correct that I can update UI from here  //do stuff with object (for example namelbl.text=unwrappedPokemon.name

Comment: I don't know whole context in your app but it is ok to update UI from here. In some cases you have to remember about make weak self to avoid retain cycle. Check an updated code

Comment: Thanks, If func downloadPokemonDetails1 is from Pokemon class and we call it from an viewcontroller viewDidload(). can we do like var pokemon: Pokemon and replace the self with pokemon?

Comment: Try it, and if it fails provide some code and we'll can try to fix it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109124/discussion-between-k8mil-and-le-khanh-vinh).